# How to build android bundle for app using Gradle script?

Tags: android, gradle, android-app-bundle

I want to upgrade my release gradle script to make android bundle instead android apk package, but I can't find the command to create bundle programmatically from gradle script instead apk.

This is what I have to convert. What is the particular command that create the apk? And what is the specified command to use to create bundle? I can't find.

```
            // copy apk file
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                if (output.outputFile != null) {
                    println "outputFile name ${output.outputFile.name}"

                    variant.assemble.doLast {
                        copy {
                            from output.outputFile
                            into destination
                            rename { String fileName ->
                                "app-${variant.productFlavors[0].name}-${buildType.name}-${versName}.apk"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I thought that was the

Answer (score 33):

You can use the command:

```
./gradlew bundle
```

or in general `./gradlew bundle<VariantName>`.

The bundle can be found at: `project-name/app/build/outputs/bundle/`

More info in the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#bundle_build_gradle).

Comment: Until today, i launch "gradlew clean :android:releaseApk" where releaseApk is "task releaseApk(dependsOn: ['prepareAlphaRelease', 'assembleRelease', 'beforeAssembleTask', 'gitCommitTag'])" and it prepare the directories, build the apk and then copy that apk files and finally it create a tag.

I tried to substitute "assembleRelease" with "bundleRelease" or "bundle" but it seems not working. It continuing to create apk instead of bundle.

I'm thinking to use the | (pipe) to do more things and to use "./gradlew bundle" ... I'm not finding any other method to do this in a better way.

Comment: You are correct to swap `assembleRelease` with `bundleRelease`. I suspect the issue comes from the other task `prepareAlphaRelease` which maybe has something hardcoded to use the `.apk` extension?

Comment: thank you @Pierre this was my big doubt (bundleRelease instead assembleRelease). Changing this, the script generate correctly the bundles (thank you!), but also the apks: it's normal that "bundleRelease" did both the formats? Anyway now it's working fine, the script generate bundles correctly.

Comment: No, the `bundleRelease` does not generate APKs. If you have APKs generated from a clean build, this comes from another task.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it says the term './gradlew' is not recognized, but I can run commands such as gradle build